# scrollbar of parent div overlaps child div

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

This issue is Chrome specific.

I have a container div with `position: fixed` and inside it I have a popup div with `position: fixed`

Only on Chrome, the scrollbar of container div overlaps my popup div. (See image attached)

Please help me get rid of scrollbar from popup div.[image]

**Edit:**
Adding Code to explain the problem:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    width:300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#messages {
    overflow: auto;
}
#messages .message {
    height: 79px;  
    background: #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px
}
.popup .videoTag {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   
    <div id="content">
        <div id="messages">
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            
            <div class="popup">
            <video class="videoTag" controls>
           <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
            </div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
           
        </div>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: If we could see your HTML markup and your CSS and any involved JavaScript that would be very useful.  Otherwise, we cannot do anything but guess and that is not useful to you. (see random guess answers...)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss added code snippet, remember issue is only on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Paste your `popup` markup outside of the `#content` div. Check the snippet below:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    width:300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#messages {
    overflow: auto;
}
#messages .message {
    height: 79px;  
    background: #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
  z-index:99;
}
.popup .videoTag {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   
    <div id="content">
        <div id="messages">
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
           
        </div>
       
    </div>
    
            
            <div class="popup">
            <video class="videoTag" controls>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried as @Commercial Suicide mentioned using `!important'. Otherwise share your code in codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: added code snippet, issue is observed on chrome only

Comment: See my comments on @Marks answer. I have additional functionality on pop-up and hence I cannot move  it out of the current hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the `overflow-y:scroll;` and the position of the `#content` and how they work in conjunction.
Simply remove the `postion:fixed;` on the `#content`.  It gets its position from its container then and should fix the issue.

Minor but `left: 200px;` on the popup was missing semi-colon - likely not in play here but tighten it up.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
#content {
    /* position: fixed;*/
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    width:300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#messages {
    overflow: auto;
 }
#messages .message {
    height: 79px;  
    background: #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
.popup .videoTag {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   
    <div id="content">
        <div id="messages">
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            
            <div class="popup">
            <video class="videoTag" controls>
           <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
            </div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
            <div class="message">example</div>
           
        </div>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position: fixed` on sidebar is added to avoid it getting scrolled when the right side of the page is being scrolled. Hence I fear that I can't remove fixed position from it.

Comment: How is it working on other browsers, and it even works on Chrome when we don't have  `video` tag inside it.

Comment: Do not know, I did not write that browser.  I just see this fixes it.

Comment: :) , sorry if I sounded rude. I was just curious :) thanks

Comment: Did not take it that way, I have a thick skin, it has to do with the interpretation of the specification and how that is worded on that specific CSS (the overflow-x and overflow-y and scroll) .  You might read the details in the specification as it has comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem only in overlapping, you can fix it via `z-index: 999`. Give this css property to your popup like this:

```
.popup {
  z-index: 999; // or more
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add `!important`? Like this: `z-index: 999 !important;`. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: It doesn't help either.

Comment: @ScrapCode, that means that the problem is somewhere else, please, share your html and css, we can't answer your question blindly, we tried, but we couldn't

Comment: added code snippet, issue is observed on chrome only.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're cool with jQuery you could do something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

<div id="content">
    <div id="messages">
        <div class="message" data-url="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">example 1 </div>
        <div class="message" data-url="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">example 2 </div>
        <div class="message" data-url="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">example 3</div>
        <div class="message" data-url="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">example 4</div>
        <div class="message" data-url="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">example 5</div>
        <div class="message" data-url="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">example 6</div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="popup">
  <video class="videoTag" controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    width:300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#messages {
    overflow: auto;
}
#messages .message {
    height: 79px;  
    background: #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
  z-index:99;
}
.popup .videoTag {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $(".message").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).data("url");
    $("video source").attr("src",url);
    $("video")[0].load();
  })
})
```

**JSFiddle (Working on Chrome too ;) )**

https://jsfiddle.net/7bkxez1f/